# Azure map indoor root navigation

Tags: geojson, mapping, autocad-map, indoor, azure-maps

We successfully show the indoor map on Azure Map .We getting a problem route navigation in indoor Azure map. can any one help me how to root navigation in Azur Map.

Is there any way to show indoor navigation using GeoJSON ,KML ,AutoCAD etc

Answer (score 0):

Indoor navigation for the Azure Maps creator is not yet released.